# Can pass data between View Controllers but Tab bar disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a Tabbed App with two tabs... the first tab has the main Action, and the second has Settings that can be updated. I am trying to pass some variables data from Settings to the Action tab. Based on some suggestions, I have used the following code for the Update button:

```
@IBAction func updateBut(_ sender: Any) {

    let myVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
    myVC.totTime = totalTime
    myVC.timeInt = intTime
    self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The data does pass to the first view controller, however, the tabs have disappeared on this view now. So, how can I get the tabs back on the screen? I am quite the beginner to any form of app development, and am just trying to learn by doing... the Tabbed App has been created using one of the Xcode New Project templates. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you creating and presenting a new copy of `FirstViewController`?

Comment: Use NotificationCenter or https://github.com/regexident/EventBus, https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
(self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as! FirstViewController).totTime = totalTime
(self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as! FirstViewController).timeInt = intTime
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: This did not work; I replaced the earlier code in IBAction with the above. The VC changed when Update button was clicked, and the First VC came up with the Tab Bar, but the data did not get updated.

Answer (score 0):

A much better way to pass data by using protocols, you can define a protocol like below

```
protocol PassDataDelegate{
    func updateFirstVc(totalTime:String)
}
```

and in your `SecondViewController` class have a delegate property like below

```
class SecondViewController:UIViewController{
    myDelegate:PassDataDelegate?//declaration part

    @IBAction func updateBut(_ sender: Any) {
        myDelegate.updateFirstVc(totalTime:totalTime)
    }
}
```

And finally in your `UITabController` class implement the protocol

```
class myTabController:UITabController,PassDataDelegate{
    var firstController:FirstViewController? //declaration part
    var secondController:SecondViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //initialize your view controller here 
        self.firstViewController = FirstViewController()
        self.secondViewController = SecondViewController()
        self.secondViewController.myDelegate = self //assign delegate to second vc
        self.viewcontrollers = [firstController, secondController]
    }

    updateFirstVc(totalTime:totalTime){
        self.firstViewController?.totTime = totalTime
        self.selectedIndex = 0// here change the tab to first vc if you want to switch the tab after passing data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false` try this

Comment: This did not work, tried it in both the View Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to iOS correct me If I am wrong,

The reason why the TabBar is not visible since you are instantiating new `FirstViewController` which is present on top of your TabBar.
TabBar by default does this Job or Add the new viewController to the TabBar Stack.

```
tabBarController.viewControllers.append(myVC)
```

For passing the data TabBar holds the reference of all its ViewControllers. So you can set or get in each other ViewControllers like this

```
var yourData{
   set{
      let yourVC = self.tabBarController?.viewController[0] as? FirstViewController ?? ErrorClass
      yourVC.dataObj = newValue
   }
   get{
      let yourVC = self.tabBarController?.viewController[0] as? FirstViewController ?? ErrorClass
       return yourVC.dataObj
     }
```